# building a trie where each node contains a token instead of a character in python

Tags: python, trie

is there a walkthrough on building a trie where each node contains a token or a word instead of a character in python?

all the trie constructions i've seen on the web have each node containing a character. I'm looking if there are references on a trie where each node contains a token or a word instead of a character.

Comment: what did you try? Did you try to use word instead of char ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257286/can-i-use-a-trie-that-has-a-whole-word-on-each-node